# How to flash images to nvidia Shield Tv (16gb)

Tags: android, nvidia, android-tv, rom

I truing  create custom ROM for nvidia Shield Tv.
Following by official instruction for getting [source code](http://nv-tegra.nvidia.com/gitweb/?p=manifest/android/binary.git;a=blob_plain;f=README_SHIELD;hb=rel-24-foster-r7-partner).

I'm built [source code](http://nv-tegra.nvidia.com/gitweb/?p=manifest/android/binary.git;a=blob_plain;f=README_SHIELD;hb=rel-24-foster-r7-partner) and ported *.img* files to the device.
But: all AOSP nvidia system worked faulty.

- Standard Android UI, not leanback TV API, and not NVIDIA custom launcher.
- Can't navigate the standard Android UI sufficiently without also using a mouse.
- Image contains no Google Apps
- No apparent Ethernet option in settings. - Need to investigate whether this can be enabled, missing driver etc.
- No Google apps in the AOSP, could be side-loaded.
- Browser App still crashes, even with WiFi connected (Missing webview component that comse from Play Store).
- Bluetooth appears to be detecting devices, but cannot get Shield controllers to pair
- Accelerated Codecs are NOT available, only the Google software codecs are included.
- Logitech PTZ Pro camera does work (though camera App appears to be not properly available)

Could somebody gives me pieces of advice how to create normal custom ROM for nvidia shield TV.

Comment: Logs via android studio shows that missing lib.
_phs:governor: failed to load "libgov_boot.so": No such file or directory_
Found the same problem on oficial shield forum. https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/924251/android-development/open-source-build-for-k1-doesn-t-include-the-camera/
But apparently community around development for this device not cultivated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected. AOSP is a portion of Android TV, but it lacks Google Apps and the TV stack that is on top of AOSP. You will have to sideload all of the additional apps in your ROM.

Your camera app probably won't work as there is no native support for mapping an external camera to the camera APIs.

Comment: I installed Gapps but they not worked. logs shows missing lib.